# Get data from SQLite as an array and generate charts with the data using Chart.js in an HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, chart.js

I'm currently working on a web app, where I want to put some data visualization on one page. The data I use to generate the visual is from an SQLite database stored locally in my machine. Based on the documentation of [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/), it will take an array and generate charts based on that, and the code is put in an HTML file under  tag, so basically it is JavaScript code.

Below is the code from Chartjs documentation I am using.

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: *there will be the data array from my SQLite*,
            backgroundColor: [
            ],
            borderColor: [
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
    }]
    }
});
</script>
```

Therefore, I need to get the data from my SQLite database, convert the field I want charts from to an array, and pass the array to the data field.

So my question is, is it possible to do this? I know some Node.js, thus I have no difficulties getting data from database with the help of require() and Sequelize. Yet I still find myself almost helpless when I want to do basically the same thing with JavaScript. Or, is it possible if I get the data array ready using Node.js, then somehow let it pass the array to the HTML file?

Thanks!

- Edit:
  Below is the project structure

```html
C:\USERS\XLYU0\VUE\PRACTICE\SQLITENODEJS\USER_AUTHEN
|   app.js
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   
+---config
|       auth.js
|       database.js
|       passport.js
|       
+---models
|       CONTACT_TIME.js
|       USER.js
|           
+---public
|   |   bootstrap.css
|   |   
|   +---css
|   |       style.css
|   |       
|   \---JS
|           sqlite.js
|           
+---routes
|       contacts.js
|       index.js
|       services.js
|       statistics.js
|       uploads.js
|       users.js
|       
\---views
    |   contacts.ejs
    |   dashboard.ejs
    |   layout.ejs
    |   layoutB.ejs
    |   login.ejs
    |   register.ejs
    |   services.ejs
    |   statistics.ejs
    |   uploads.ejs
    |   welcome.ejs
    |   
    \---partials
            messages.ejs
```

The JS code for generating charts is in statistics.ejs, and I intend to put code that gets data from the database in JS/sqlite.js, though I suppose it'll be okay it goes to statistics.ejs as well as long as it is JavaScript.

The SQLite file is stored somewhere else in my machine locally, and now I know how to connect to it by following [instructions](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/), and here is what I got for now.

```js
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('../../../../../../database.db');

let reportingTag = [];

let sql = `SELECT * FROM CONTACT_TIME`;

db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    reportingTag.push(row.reportingTag);
  });
  
  console.log(reportingTag);

});



// close the database connection
db.close();
```

- Edit: here is my current progress

```js
const express = require('express')
const CONTACT = require('../models/CONTACT_TIME')
const { render } = require('ejs')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    CONTACT.findAll().then((contacttime) =>{

        const context = {
            contextContactTime: contacttime.map(contacttime =>{
                return{
                    id: contacttime.id,
                    reportingTag: contacttime.reportingTag,
                }
            })
        }
        let tags = []
        context.contextContactTime.forEach((contact) =>{
            tags.push(contact.reportingTag)
        })
        res.send(tags)
})})

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('statistics', { layout: 'layoutB' }))


module.exports = router
```

I managed to send the data via Express.js router, yet I also want the template engine to render the page so I called res.render() below as well. Then it seems that the next step is to retrieve data on statistics.ejs. Though I know how to display data on the page directly with ejs, I have trouble accessing data w/ JavaScript. I need to do this since to generate charts with Chart.js I need to write some code between  tag.

Comment: Anything is possible. Could you please provide more info about the use case? That will allow us to temper our answers.

Comment: @Khobalt Thanks for your reply. I've added some more info though I'm not sure if I understand 'use case'.

Comment: OK cool. Much better. So you're trying to get some info from the server to the client. I'd recommend trying Express.js and making a simple REST API with it. At your skill level I think you could accomplish your goal from a 10 minute tutorial, armed with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to passing your data from tag body to tag script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <title>Documment</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas>
        </canvas>
        <p id="data" style="display:none"><%= value %></p>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    // your data change to string
    let data = document.getElementById("data").innerText 
  
    let array = data.split(',')
</script>
</html>
```